# ¿Cómo se añaden o eliminan elementos en los arrays de javascript en una posición determinada?

Tags: javascript, array

Sé que puedo declarar un array en JavaScript de este modo `var miArray = [];`, también puedo añadir elementos con `miArray.push(elemento);`.

Pero: **¿Como añado o elimino elementos en una posición determinada?**

He visto que existe `splice()` y que hace las dos cosas (borrar y añadir) pero no acabo de entender correctamente el funcionamiento con los ejemplos que he encontrado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para añadir un elemento en una posición determinada:

```
miArray.splice(posicion, 0, elemento);
```

Para quitar un elemento:

```
miArray.splice(posicion, 1);
```

La sintaxis general es ([referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)):

```
miArray.splice(
    posicion, 
    cuantos-elementos-se-quitan,
    elemento-que-se-añade-1, 
    elemento-que-se-añade-2, ...)
```

...y devuelve un array con los elementos que se han quitado.

Ten en cuenta que la primera posición es la 0.

Ejemplo usando el modo interactivo de node.js:

```
> x = [1,2,3,4]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
> x.splice(2, 0, 99)
[]
> x
[ 1, 2, 99, 3, 4 ]
> x.splice(3, 1)
[ 3 ]
> x
[ 1, 2, 99, 4 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Para añadir un elemento en un posición determinada de un array tienes la función splice. Que modifica el array insertando o borrando elementos y devuelve el array de los elementos que se quitaron (si se quitó alguno).
El primer parámetro es el índice donde se desea añadir y/o borrar elementos, el segundo el número de elementos a borrar y los siguientes los elementos a insertar en la posición indicada. Ejemplo:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.splice(2, 1, "Lemon", "Kiwi");
```

El resultado de splice es un array de los elementos eliminados, en este caso ["Apple"] y fruits contiene ahora Banana,Orange,**Lemon,Kiwi**,Mango. Como ves se inserta Lemon y Kiwi en la posición 2 del array y en como se indica que hay que quitar un elemento quita el de la posición 2 en ese instante, Apple.

Además de push que te añade el elemento al final del array está la función unshift que te permite añadir uno o varios elementos al inicio del array. Ejemplo:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.unshift("Lemon","Pineapple");
```

El resultado de unshift es el número de elementos del array, y fruits a partir de ahora contiene Lemon,Pineapple,Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma muy eficiente de eliminar elementos de una lista, sobre todo si son muchos, es usar `filter`. Este método crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos del array original que pasen un test; el test es una función que pasas como parámetro. Por ejemplo, para obtener solo los elementos pares de un array:

```
var l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var l2 = l.filter(function (i) { return i % 2 === 0 });
assert(l2.length === 3);
assert(l2[0] === 2);
assert(l2[1] === 4);
assert(l2[3] === 6);
```

Para añadir datos, otra opción además de la comentada por konamiman es el método `push`, que añade el valor suministrado como parámetro como último elemento del array:

```
var l = [1, 2];
l.push(3);
assert(l.length === 3);
assert(l[0] === 1);
assert(l[1] === 2);
assert(l[2] === 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar puede utilizar:

```
arreglo=["uno","dos","tres","tres"]
var item="tres";
arreglo=arreglo.filter( e => e !== item );
```